# Firebase observeSigleEvent or observe

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi all I am trying to retrieve data from firebase

Here is a picture of it
[image]

In this case:

```
    self.ref.child("Events").child("2").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {snap in
            //let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let event = snap.value as? [[String:Any]]
            print(snap.value)
            let end_time_test = event?["end_time"] as? String
```

event is nil, it's supposed to put an array in it, it works here

```
self.ref.child("Events").child("2").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                for child in snapshot.children{

            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let event = snap.value as? [String:Any]
                print(event )
```

I'm new to firebase requests thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you enabled the persistence ?

Comment: If you add `print(snap)` what does it print for `observeSingleEvent ` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe is used to get the initial value and after it you get notified if there is something changing.

Observe single event is used to fetch the data only once.

Comment: Ok so were is the problem here, retrieving a single array (event and its details) is exactly what i want to do, went I print snap.value it returns something so with my event array is nil?

Comment: I think it is let event = snap.value as? [[String:Any]] or only as? Array

Comment: yes! I can now print it but I have a problem with :

 let end_time_test = event?["end_time"] as? String

Comment: now it should be event[0]?["end_time"] as? String. You understand the problem?

Comment: Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String : Any]]' with an index of type 'String'

Comment: Then do. let myEvent = event[0] as! [String:Any]. And then myEvent["end_time"] as? String.

Comment: worked with : let end_time_test = event?[0]["end_time"] as? String. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help. But try to understand what we did now. It is not that hard :)

Comment: Hi I have another little question, I looked over it for the passed 30mins could you give it a try?
https://imgur.com/a/WK5WL

Comment: let location = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "place").childSnapshot(forPath: "location").value as? [[String:Any]]

Comment: Latitude and longitude at least that's what interests me https://imgur.com/a/WK5WL (extended firebase data)

Comment: The problem is, if you follow your event stuff it need to be something like event?[0]["place"][location] as! [String:Any]. But you declared your event like [[String:Any]] so the next objects don't know what they are. So what you have to do is. let place = event?[0][place] as! [String:Any]. let location = place["location"] as! [String:Any].

Comment: And then something like location["latitude"] as! Float or what ever you have there

Comment: Worked fine... Thanks!!

Comment: "Observe is used to get notified if there is something changing." When you observe a location **you get notified of the initial value** and of any changes.

Comment: You are right, but at the end, if you have nothing and then observe it, the first thing you get compared to nothing is a change :). But to be correct, I changed the sentence.

Comment: Any idea what this means for the battery of the device running it?

Comment: @christostsang Im not sure about this, but if I remember correctly Firebase is holding an socket connection to the backend anyways. So maybe there is not much more energy impact on this site. But on the opposite, every time another device is updating the value you observe, there will be traffic to get you notified, even you don't need the value.